# hide a label after some time automatically after a buttonclick

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am Working in ASP.NET and C#.

In my Application i have a registration form in which there is a label which shows the **success** and **failure** of the registration.The text for that label is from codebehind based on the condition.Now what i need is to hide the label after sometime (say 5sec) on clicking the submit button.I have tried this using javascript but its not working properly.please let me know whats the mistake or give ur sugessions.

**Script**:

```
    function HideLabel() {
        document.getElementById('<%= lbl1.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
    }
    setTimeout("HideLabel();", 5000);
```

Comment: do you mind using jquery?. You can add fadeIN and fade out

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have wrong syntax of [setTimout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp). You have to pass name of function, remove the quotes and also pass name not call the function. One more thing to take care is to put the code just before the closing `body` tag to ensure the availability of html elements.

Change

```
setTimeout("HideLabel();", 5000);
```

To

```
setTimeout(HideLabel, 5000);
```